# Automated Locating and Selecting Files From File Explorer using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyautogui, microsoft-file-explorer

Im having trouble finding a solution to my problem anywhere online, so i made my account and this is my first post :)

I'm using PyAutoGUI to automate uploading videos to a website from a folder. When the automation clicks the "Select Files" button on the website, it opens File Explorer and asks me to choose a file, now this is the part i cant find a solution to, **how to select a video**.

**Currently I'm using** nooby weak code, where the PyAutoGUI presses (in file explorer) *ctrl+f* then enters video+number(*video1, video2*,..), it finds the video, and clicks arrow buttons 'down', *'down', 'up', 'left',* so it hovers over the right video, and presses *enter* to confirm video and continue automation to post it. As shown:

(Because of this way of approach, videos in the folder are named video1, video2, video3,...)

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'f')
print("- selecting video number: {}".format(number), end='')

pyautogui.write("video{}".format(number))

pyautogui.hotkey('enter')

pyautogui.hotkey('down', 'down', 'up', 'left')

pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

This surpisingly works very well, even when video number hits double digits.
I want to completely change this part of the code as I am planning to present this project in school, and want the code to be sturdy and more advanced then...

```
pyautogui.hotkey('down', 'down', 'up', 'left')
```

So any suggestions on how i could implement **navigating ** the file explorer with or along side to the PyAutoGUI automation to select videos either by name or from a selected folder, one by one.

Any suggestions are welcome, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use pyautogui.locateOnScreen to locate a screenshot of an object. You will get a coordinate then you can click directly at the file name input then type the name of your video.

```
coordX, coordY = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("cropped_screenshot.png")
pyautogui.click(coordX + 200, coordY) #<---example the real object to click is 200 pixels to the right
pyautogui.write("video{}".format(number))
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

This way you can present that you are able to find any object on the screen and interact with it

Comment: Thank you for your answer Farid, I use locateOnScreen in other parts of the code, and its a nice tool, but in some situations (like this one), its unreliable. In this example, there are multiple identical icons on the screen and it get's it wrong most of the time. Again, thanks for the answer, best regards, Lanko

Comment: After you selected the video, would it fill in the path of the video in the website form? If that's true, you can just fill in the path of the video directly into the form instead of clicking "Select Videos". This way you wont even have to deal with the pop up window